# How to set up CmakeList flags

Tags: c++, cmake, compiler-flags

This is the way how I compile my cpp code:

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include/modbus `pkg-config glib-2.0 --cflags --libs` -L/usr/local/lib -lmodbus test-modbus.c -o test-modbus
```

with gcc it is working pretty fine. But I need to place it into CmakeList.txt and I tried this:

```
SET(GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS "-I/usr/local/include/modbus -L/usr/local/lib")
SET(GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS    "-lmodbus")
SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS}" )
SET( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS}" )
```

But with no success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

CMake aims to be platform- and compiler-independent, so you don't set specific compiler flags, but you tell CMake what you want to do. For example, the `include_directories` command adds directories to the include path (similar to gcc's `-I`  option), `target_link_libraries` links a library (similar to gcc's `-l`) option, `pkg_config` can be called through the `PkgConfig` module, and so on.